# convert cte to connect by in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, recursive-query, connect-by

I have below cte query which works in 11g but not in 10g. How can I write the same for 10g using connect by. not sure if its possible.. or I need to write the cursor/while loop to for the same.
The sample data is here [Recursive sql server query 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347910/recursive-sql-server-query-4)

```
With Cte(Object_id,Parent_id) AS
(
SELECT 

       spl.object_id, 
       spl.folder_id
FROM   table1 spl 

WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   table2 spt 
                   WHERE  spl.object_id = spt.object_id) 
       AND spl.staged = 0 

)
, recursive_cte (object_id,Parent_id,objectname2) AS 
(
    SELECT  
     object_id
    ,Parent_id
    ,CAST('' as varchar(201)) objectname2
     FROM Cte 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    recursive_cte.object_id, 
    sf.parent_id, 
     CAST(sf.object_name as varchar(100)) || '\' || CAST(recursive_cte.objectname2 as varchar(100)) 
      FROM table3 sf
    INNER JOIN recursive_cte ON recursive_cte.Parent_id = sf.object_id
)
select * from recursive_cte;
```

Comment: The table structures, some sample data and expected output might be helpful. Maybe you can set up an SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @AlexPoole added link to sample data

Comment: The t1 from that question doesn't have a `staged` column, or `folder_id`; and you haven't shown `table3`?

Comment: @AlexPoole my bad.. can you please provide a connect by solution based on the sample data.